# rethinkdb or where query on php driver

Tags: php, rethinkdb

I'm using [rethinkdb PHP driver](http://danielmewes.dnsalias.net/~daniel/php-rql-api/) and I'm trying to perform an `or` `where` query, below is what I've tried

```
$query = r\db('cn_chat')->table('messages')->filter(
         r\row('origin')->eq('connectnigeria')->or(r\row('origin')->eq('business'))
        )->run($conn);
```

But no luck, any help, ideas please.

it returns

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method r\Queries\Math\Eq::or()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the documentation you attached (http://danielmewes.dnsalias.net/~daniel/php-rql-api/#Math+and+logic),

the **or** should be **rOr**:

```
$query = r\db('cn_chat')->table('messages')->filter(
     r\row('origin')->eq('connectnigeria')->rOr(r\row('origin')->eq('business'))
    )->run($conn);
```